# Laravel Nova - How to remove image from disk when corresponding database entry is removed?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I'm new to Laravel and Nova and want to built a `Resource` that allows the storing of an `image`, together with some other data. After upload, the `image file` is stored on the `disk` (`storage/app/public`) while all other data (including the `image link`) is stored in the database.

**`stored image`**:

[image]

**`database`**:

[image]

When I remove this database entry in `Nova` the `stored image` is unaffected by it. Won't this overflow my storage in production? Does `Nova` come with a way to `clear unused images from disk` or do I have to manually remove it with Laravel? In either case I'd appreciate help.

This is the **`fields`** function of my **`Resource`**:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),
        Text::make('Heading'),
        Text::make('Content'),
        File::make('Image')->disk('public'),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Nova doc](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/file-fields.html) provides a simple solution for this by adding `prunable` to the `Image function` (or any other `File function`):

```
Image::make('Profile Photo')->disk('public')->prunable()
```

This way images are deleted from the storage when image is deleted or updated.